# Is there any way to get rid of the TOC page with iBooks Author?

Tags: books

I'm making a picture book with iBooks Author. Each page is one simple image. That's all there is to the book.

So I don't need the TOC. Is there a way to get rid of the TOC?

Comment: Not entirely, but there is a work around http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akQprtIl6Sw&feature=player_detailpage

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.. Open the document, select the inspector, select the TOC tab. Highlight each section and press the minus key. See the images... You'd have to preview it on your iPad, and mine is not here right now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]